# Masstransit 8 does not allow to response a message within scope filter anymore

Tags: .net, masstransit

After migrating to Masstransit 8.0.3 the ScopeFilter does allow to respond and end the consumer process within the Send(ConsumeContext...) method. In our case we are having a cache scope filter with a mediator setup. There is a CacheScopeFilter during the Consume Send method it checks if something is in the in-memory cache for the specific request:

```
                var cacheResponse = cacheService.GetCachedResponse(cacheRequest);
                if (cacheResponse != null)
                {
                    logger.LogInformation(
                        $"Take data from cache {requestName} {context.Message}, CacheKey: {cacheRequest}");
                    await context.RespondAsync(cacheResponse)
                    return;
                }
```

This means: Do not enter the mediator consumer, just respond the cache. In Masstransit 7.x it works. With Masstransit 8 it says "message not consumed"

One way to solve it is to write the result in the message payload and let the consumer check for caching results first. But all mediator consumers must by amended which I would like to avoid.

Stacktrace:

```
===> 10:41:53.689 +00:00 [Error] Middleware caught unhandled exception of type "RequestException".
MassTransit.RequestException: An exception occurred while processing the GetFooByIdQuery request
 ---> MassTransit.MessageNotConsumedException: loopback://localhost/mediator => The message was not consumed
   at MassTransit.Middleware.FaultDeadLetterFilter.Send(ReceiveContext context, IPipe`1 next) in /_/src/MassTransit/Middleware/FaultDeadLetterFilter.cs:line 11
   at MassTransit.Middleware.DeadLetterFilter.MassTransit.IFilter<MassTransit.ReceiveContext>.Send(ReceiveContext context, IPipe`1 next) in /_/src/MassTransit/Middleware/DeadLetterFilter.cs:line 39
   at MassTransit.Transports.ReceivePipeDispatcher.Dispatch(ReceiveContext context, ReceiveLockContext receiveLock) in /_/src/MassTransit/Transports/ReceivePipeDispatcher.cs:line 62
   at MassTransit.Transports.ReceivePipeDispatcher.Dispatch(ReceiveContext context, ReceiveLockContext receiveLock) in /_/src/MassTransit/Transports/ReceivePipeDispatcher.cs:line 89
   at MassTransit.Transports.ReceivePipeDispatcher.Dispatch(ReceiveContext context, ReceiveLockContext receiveLock) in /_/src/MassTransit/Transports/ReceivePipeDispatcher.cs:line 95
   at MassTransit.Mediator.Contexts.MediatorSendEndpoint.SendMessage[T](T message, IPipe`1 pipe, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/MassTransit/Mediator/Contexts/MediatorSendEndpoint.cs:line 210
   at MassTransit.Mediator.Contexts.MediatorSendEndpoint.SendMessage[T](T message, IPipe`1 pipe, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/MassTransit/Mediator/Contexts/MediatorSendEndpoint.cs:line 220
   at MassTransit.Clients.RequestSendEndpoint`1.Send(Guid requestId, TRequest message, IPipe`1 pipe, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/MassTransit/Clients/RequestSendEndpoint.cs:line 43
   at MassTransit.Clients.RequestClient`1.<>c__DisplayClass11_0`2.<<GetResponse>g__Request|0>d.MoveNext() in /_/src/MassTransit/Clients/RequestClient.cs:line 104
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at MassTransit.Clients.ClientRequestHandle`1.SendRequest()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at MassTransit.Clients.ClientRequestHandle`1.SendRequest() in /_/src/MassTransit/Clients/ClientRequestHandle.cs:line 170
   at MassTransit.Clients.RequestClient`1.GetResponseInternal[T1,T2](SendRequestCallback request, CancellationToken cancellationToken, RequestTimeout timeout, RequestPipeConfiguratorCallback`1 callback) in /_/src/MassTransit/Clients/RequestClient.cs:line 212
   at MassTransit.Clients.ResponseHandlerConnectHandle`1.GetTask() in /_/src/MassTransit/Clients/ResponseHandlerConnectHandle.cs:line 53
   at Hcv.Dev.Service.Api.Controllers.Queries.FooQueryControllerMitarbeiter.GetMitarbeiterGetFooAsync(Guid id) in C:\net\hcvision\Hcv-Core\dev\Microservices\ApiServices\Hcv.Dev.Service.Api\Controllers\Queries\FooQueryControllerMitarbeiter.cs:line 30
   at lambda_method155(Closure , Object )
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.AwaitableObjectResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, ValueTask`1 actionResultValueTask)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeInnerFilterAsync>g__Awaited|13_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|20_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow :)

Answer (score 0):

If I recall, the only thing you need to change is the filter so that it calls `context.NotifyConsumed`. There was another discussion/question that had the same issue.

So, something like:

```cs
await context.RespondAsync(cacheResponse)
context.NotifyConsumed(TimeSpan.Zero, "CacheFilter");
```

This will signal that the message was consumed properly (by the filter, this is automatically called for a consumer and should not otherwise be called ever).

> Link to the [previous discussion](https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/discussions/3272).

A complete filter example from the above linked discussion:

```cs
public class SubmitFilter<T> : IFilter<ConsumeContext<T>>
    where T : class
{
    public void Probe(ProbeContext context)
    {
    }

    public async Task Send(ConsumeContext<T> context, IPipe<ConsumeContext<T>> next)
    {
        await context.NotifyConsumed(context.ReceiveContext.ElapsedTime, TypeCache<SubmitFilter<T>>.ShortName);

        await context.RespondAsync<OrderStatus>(new("It works from filter"));
    }
}
```